# MySQL Join not returning data that matches in both tables in new database instance

Tags: mysql, database, join, instance

I've been lurking here for a few months and learning a lot from reading other questions, but this is the first time I've been brave enough to ask one!

```
SELECT  * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.tableBid = a.tableBid
WHERE a.tableAcol = 'paramValue';
```

I only have 39 rows in table B and for everyone of these there IS a row in tableA for paramValue with a matching tableBid, so I would expect to get 39 rows back.  And indeed in  another database instance I do.

I can't see any significant differences in the instances, though this could be ignorance, but in this new instance I only get 7 records with the same query.

If I change the query to

```
SELECT  * FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.tableBid = a.tableBid
WHERE a.tableAcol = 'paramValue';
```

or

```
SELECT  * FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.tableBid = b.tableBid
WHERE a.tableAcol = 'paramValue';
```

then I get the 39 rows I expect with a.tableBid matching b.tableBid in all cases and no nulls

I am clearly confused.  Can anyone explain this please.

Can't post the real data but I can reproduce it

```
 CREATE TABLE tableB (  
tableBid varchar(30) NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
nameB varchar(25) NOT NULL  ,
description varchar(40) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE tableA (
userID varchar(30) NOT NULL,
tableBid Varchar(30) NOT NULL,
info varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(userID, tableBID));

insert into tableB (tableBid, nameB, description)
values 
('a', 'a name', 'blah'),
('b', 'b name', 'blah'),
('c', 'c name', 'blah'),
('d', 'd name', 'blah');

insert into tableA (userID, tableBid, info)
values
('deel','a',  'blah'),
('deel','b',  'blah'),
('deel','c',  'blah'),
('deel','d',  'blah');
```

Then

```
SELECT  * FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.tableBid = a.tableBid
WHERE a.userID = 'deel';
```

gives me 4 rows:

```
deel    a   blah    a   a name  blah
deel    b   blah    b   b name  blah
deel    c   blah    c   c name  blah
deel    d   blah    d   d name  blah
```

But

```
SELECT  * FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.tableBid = a.tableBid
WHERE a.userID = 'deel';
```

gives me

```
deel    d   blah    d   d name  blah
```

**Tables definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE `tablea` (
   `userID` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `tableBid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `info` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`tableBid`)
 ) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `tableb` (
   `tableBid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `nameB` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   `description` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`tableBid`)
 ) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: If you get your results with your LEFT JOIN and not with your INNER JOIN, then it's probably a data issue from TableB.  Post your data and we can confirm.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes The only difference between LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN should be the addition of rows with null b.*. Something is indeed very weird.

Comment: @Barmar -- yes, I realize that.  That means with the Inner Join, the OP has missing data in TableB...

Comment: @sgeddes But he said "I get the 39 rows ... and no nulls". I suspect his actual code has a typo.

Comment: @Barmar -- fair point -- need to see that data :)

Comment: Thanks for responses.  Unfortunately I can't post the real data.  I'll see if I can reproduce with mock data  (PS he is a she :) )

Comment: @Dee Is it a confidentiality issue? Change your queries to SELECT a.tableAid, b.tableBid and you should be able post the relevant data.

Comment: @Dee The two LEFT JOIN examples are identical (it doesn't matter the order in the ON clause). What if you `SELECT * FROM tableB LEFT JOIN tableA ON ...`?

Comment: @DeeLindesay what do you expect the result to be for each query that you posted?  Based on your sample, both queries are working -- see this sql fiddle demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ae0b/6

Comment: @jmilloy  I thought that the left join examples were the same,but thought maybe that I  could  be wrong hence the second example.

Comment: @Barmar reproduced with mock data above.  1 row from one query, 4 from the other, but all rows are matched

Comment: Are both `tableBid` columns of the same datatype (`Varchar(30)`) and same character set and collation?

Comment: @sqlfiddle - The results you get is exactly what I would expect, but in this new database instance I am only getting one row returned from the JOIN without the LEFT bit.

Comment: @ypercube  Both varchar(30) set above.  Not sure what you mean by character set and collation, but I have literally run the create and query as above and get this weird result.

Comment: Can't reproduce it, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/213fb/1

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableA;` and the same for tableB? And also tell us which exact version of MySQL you are using? this looks more and more like a bug.

Comment: @ypercube putting in the trims on the inner join gives me the expected 4 rows.  Oddly, I only need one trim and it works which ever side I put it.  Does this mean that the data is being padded out - I'm not entering any spaces.  And if it is why does one of the rows still join successfully.

Comment: @ypercube  Added the show create.  Will see if I can find out version number.

Comment: Can you also run `SHOW CHARACTER SET FOR mydatabase;` and `SHOW CHARACTER SET FOR mydatabase.tableA;` and `SHOW CHARACTER SET FOR mydatabase.tableB;` I think that this is either a collation problem or a bug in the Xeround engine.

Comment: If I do show character set I get a lot of gobble-dl-gook :)

Comment: I can't get workbence to accept SHOW CHARACTER SET FOR - it doesn't like the FOR bit?

Comment: Version stuff:  protocol_version 10
version 5.1.42
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: Can you try something else? Adding an index: `ALTER TABLE tableA ADD INDEX tableBid_IX (tableBid);` and then run the queries again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24216/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dee-lindesay)

Comment: @DeeLindesay stupid perhaps but have you tried restarting your database? I have tested your case in SQL fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87b07/1) and my local mysql database but I can not replicate your bug.

Comment: I have tried your query on windows 7 and Ubuntu. In Ubuntu I encountered a lot of errors, until I realized that this might be due to the fact that the linux version only accepts lowercase names. However, after I realized my mistake I wasn't able to replicate your bug.

Comment: @Mr.Radical Notice that the OP is using the Xeround engine. It may be a problem related to that only and not to other engines.

Comment: @ypercube I think the problem is also with the Xeround engine. I didn't mentioned it but I  tried other engines and they work. The exception in this case it use of another type of engine Xeround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logical assumption from your queries output: **If this happens, it's a bug.**

After the reveal that you are using the **Xeround engine**, I think that you should write up the test case you have gathered and submit it as a bug in their bug list or forum.

Comment: I have raised this with Xeround support and am waiting for their response.  Btw char_length(tableBid) returns lengths of 1 for both tables which makes a nonsense of the trim working.  I'll post back when I get an answer from Xeround

Comment: @ypercupe xeround's response: "Our R&D experts solved this issue." and everything now works as I expected it to.